# Number of elements in direct product of two groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, least-common-multiple, direct-product

Trying to solve this question for the following groups and not quite sure how to do it.

Given:
i) $G1 = ℤ_{11}, G2 = ℤ_{12}$ | order 4
ii) $G1 = U(19), G2 = U(19)$ | order 6
iii) $G1 = D_4, G2 =Q_8$ | order 4

I want to find the number of elements of the given order in $G1×G2$.

Now using what I know, trying for the first one, 
$|(a,b)| = lcm(|a|, |b|) = 4 \implies ... ?$

Now I thought it would imply $(|a|, |b|) = (4,1), (4,2)$ but that leads me to 4 which isn't the correct answer. The notes I'm using are a bit confusing so I was hoping for clarification and help with regards to answering this. Thanks!

Comment: How can $|a|$ be $4$ if $a \in \mathbb Z_{11}$? By Lagrange's theorem, the order of any element must be a divisor of the order of the group. So $|a|$ must divide $11$, hence $|a|$ must be either $1$ or $11$. Obviously $11$ won't work, so...

Comment: Oh I was misunderstanding where they got the values for $|a|$ in my notes, and took it to be the divisors of the order given. But of course, what you said makes more sense. $|a|$ must be either $1$ or $11$ (but clearly not $11$) and $|b|$ must be either $1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12$ ($6$ and $12$ not working of course). Assuming I understood correctly.

Comment: Right. And since we can exclude $|a| = 11$, we must have $|a| = 1$. Therefore $\operatorname{lcm}(|a|,|b|) = \operatorname{lcm}(1, |b|) = |b|$, so we must have $|b| = 4$. So you just need to count how many elements of order $4$ there are in $\mathbb Z_{12}$.